# grpc multiple returns types

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

What is the best approach to get one more guy in return on a service? I mean, i want a single method to be able to return more than one type, in which case the find method would return a User or a Response

```
syntax = "proto3";

service UserService {
    rpc Add(User) returns (Response);
    rpc Find(Id) returns (User);
}

message Response {
    string message = 1;
}

message Id {
    string id = 1;
}

message User {
    string id = 1;
    int32 money = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return an object that includes the response and the user.

```
    syntax = "proto3";

    service UserService {
        rpc Add(User) returns (Response);
        rpc Find(Id) returns (FindResponse);
    }
    
    message Response {
        string message = 1;
    }
    
    message Id {
        string id = 1;
    }
    
    message User {
        string id = 1;
        int32 money = 2;
    }

    message FindResponse{
        Response response = 1;
        User user = 2;
    }
```

Comment: Well yeah, thats true but the problem is that it is not scalable...

Comment: But n rpc response has only a single return value. So you have to return a struct or array and have some logic like, if user is null/empty use message... Or you have to use different service methods for different return types. That is the way it works.